# readlines function throwing an error when applied to a file obtained as a response from a webpage

Tags: python

I have the following code which is almost similar to the code in my last question :

```
import sys , os
import requests, webbrowser,bs4
from PIL import Image
import pyautogui
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ab = "Ozil is the best"

ff = ab.find("zil")

print (ff) 
print( ab[1:len(ab)])


p = requests.get('http://www.goal.com/en-ie/news/ozil-agent-eviscerates-jealous-keown-over-stupid-comments/1javhtwzz72q113dnonn24mnr1')
j = "                                                                                                                                                          "
n = open("exml.txt" , 'wb')
for i in p.iter_content(1000) :
    n.write(i)


n.close()
n = open("exml.txt",'rb')
lis_lines = n.readlines()
#print (lis_lines[0])
#print(yy.encode("ascii"))
yy = lis_lines[0]
k = yy.find(".png")
#print(yy.decode("ascii"))
#yy = lis_lines[0].split(".png" , lis_lines[0].count(".png"))
#print(yy.encode("ascii"))
soupy= bs4.BeautifulSoup(p,"lxml")
#print(yy.encode("ascii"))
#print(yy)
```

What I intended to do is to have a script which will save all the images in the webpage in my system .

In the script of the last question I was set out to do it with "select" attribute of beautifulSoup .

In the script of the last question I was set out to do it with "select" attribute of beautifulSoup .

However , there I was stuck with some errors as such I thought I will read the xml file and find all the places where ".png" is present and from there I will move back one character at a time till I reach "WWW". 
In this way I will form a list of strings which will be having a list of links to the images in the webpage . Then one by one , I will use the webbrowser module to open these links and will take a screenshot and save it to some directory in my computer .

However . I am getting an error in the following line :

```
 k = yy.find(".png")
```

It states  :

*File "C:\perl\webscratcher.py", line 27, in 
    k = yy.find(".png")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'*

I need to understand this error in depth . I think I was reading it in binary mode that's why it expects byte type data to be searched in the string . 
So , how to avoid this ? I need to understand this concept in depth to be very clear about this .

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `rb` mode when reading the file. Replace `n = open("exml.txt",'rb')` with `n = open("exml.txt",'r')`.

Btw, when posting questions on Stack Overflow, try to make your question as minimal as possible. For instance, remove the commented lines and use more descriptive variable names.

Comment: @gilev : The problem is I am getting the following error when I am using "r" , :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\perl\webscratcher.py", line 23, in <module>
    lis_lines = n.readlines()
  File "C:\Users\PREMRAJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 8164: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: You could also write the content without `wb`, but only with `w`. 

Or you could convert the read bytes to string, but if there is no particular reason to save bytes, I think saving plain string is simpler.